# Read data from CSV into a single array or a single json

Tags: php

I am using jQuery autocomplete function. For it to work I need the json in this format ["Alaska","Alabama","Arkansas"] . Currently I am reading the data from a CSV file. This is my code.

```
$f = fopen($filename, "r");
    while ($row = fgetcsv($f)) {
            $out = $row[2];
            print_r (explode(" , ",$out));
        }
```

Now I get the output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alaska
)
Array
(
    [0] => Alabama
)
Array
(
    [0] => Arkansas
)
```

And my Json as

```
["Alaska"]["Romeo"]["Arkansas"]
```

How do I convert the array into a simple array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alaska
    [1] => Alabama
    [2] => Arkansas
)
```

If not into a json like this

```
["Alaska","Alabama","Arkansas"]
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#114764

Comment: Your results seem to suggest that the `explode()` call isn't doing anything useful and could be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build an array of values and then put them in `json_encode()` function.

```
$data = [];
$f = fopen($filename, "r");
    while ($row = fgetcsv($f)) {
            $out = $row[2];
            $data = array_merge($data, explode(" , ",$out)));
        }

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to read the file into an arary, map to a function that explodes, then encode and display:

```
echo json_encode(
    array_map(function($v) { return explode(" , ", $v)[2]; }, file($filename))
);
```